# In a string, how to find the index of the first character of the nth occurrence of a substring Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

Suppose I have a pretty long string `longString` and a much shorter substring `substring`. I want to find the index of the first character for the `n`th occurrence of `substring` in `longString`. In other words, suppose `substring = "stackoverflow"`, and I want to find the `n`th occurrence of `"stackoverflow"` in `longString`, and find the index of the first character of `substring` (which is the letter s).

Example:

```
longString = "stackoverflow_is_stackoverflow_not_stackoverflow_even_though_stackoverflow"
substring = "stackoverflow"
n = 2
```

Thus, in the above example, the index of the `s` in the 2nd occurrence of `"stackoverflow"` is 17.

I would like to find an efficient and fast way of doing so.

Comment: Note that the search string could overlap with itself, e.g. `abcxyzabc`, so you need to decide how you want to count a search in `abcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabc`, i.e. do you ignore the overlapping portion, or do you count it?

Comment: @Tom Karzes In my current situation, I would like to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty short way:

```
def index_of_nth_occurrence(longstring, substring, n):
    return len(substring.join(longstring.split(substring)[:n]))
    

longstring = "stackoverflow_is_stackoverflow_not_stackoverflow_even_though_stackoverflow"
substring = "stackoverflow"
n = 2

print(index_of_nth_occurrence(longstring, substring, n)
# 17
```

The trick here is using `str.split()` to find non-overlapping occurrences of the substring, then join back the first `n` of them, and check how many characters that totals up to. The very next character after would be the first character of the `n`th occurrence of the substring.

---

This may be less efficient than an iterative/manual approach, and will ignore overlapping matches, but it's quick and easy.